# Is there a way to sum multiple values looked up from an array, with a single input cell and a single output cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is tricky to describe, but should make more sense with an example. I have a simple table with two columns - a name, and a number value. For example (Town, Population).

| Name | Population |
| --- | --- |
| NY | 10 |
| LA | 15 |
| Boston | 20 |

My input values are a single cell that looks like
`NY, LA`
or
`LA, Boston, NY`

Importantly, these inputs can be of arbitrary length, they might list two cities, they might list 50. `LA, Boston, NY, A, B, C, Foo, Bar...`

I'd like to return the sum of the values related to each of the delimited cities.

So `NY, LA` returns 25 (NY = 10, LA = 15; the sum of 10 and 15 is 25) and `LA, Boston, NY` returns 45.

I'm guessing some combination of index/match and a sum function, but I can't quite get index/match to grab multiple values simultaneously from a single input cell and then manipulate those values to a single output cell.

LEFT/RIGHT/MID etc. I don't think work, due to the arbitrary length of the input string.

Any help at all would be appreciated!

For the visual learners: see an example on imgur!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ***Microsoft-365*** you can use below formula.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B9,A2:A9,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(E2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Notice the meaning of the comma and use it for exact matching：

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&A2:A4&",",",NY,LA,"))*B2:B4))
```